# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a forcing to add a Cohen real

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Are there some necessary and sufficient conditions for a forcing notion to add a Cohen real in the generic extension?

In other words, given a non-atomic forcing p.o. $\mathbb{P}$, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $\mathbb{P}$ for the existence of a complete embedding $e:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is the Cohen forcing $Fn(\omega,2)$?

Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What I would like to know is why one couldn't use an atomic p.o. $\mathbb P$ to force a cohen real (or any generic real, for that matter)?  What's so special about non-atomic partial orders, anyway?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin In terms of Boolean-valued models $V^B$, the join  of the atoms in $B$ is the truth value of "the universe is only the ground model." So to actually extend the ground model, you need to avoid atoms.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Here is a partial sufficient condition. For every forcing $\mathbb P$ which adds a real, there is a ccc forcing $\mathbb Q$ which forces that $\mathbb P$ adds a Cohen real. Consequently, under $\rm PFA$, every ccc forcing of size $\aleph_1$, adds a Cohen real. see https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/small-forcings-and-cohen-reals/86010983170A95CEEF6953A06CEE29E5

Comment: Also, see https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/cohen-reals-from-small-forcings/E64C6EF0DE81D8FEA8E77370DADC2C13

Comment: In the first  comment, I meant every forcing of size $\aleph_1$